# Custom view extension not working in Release Build

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to do e backwards compatible extension for apis available only in ios15. The following code runs successfully in Debug build but in Release build its not. So I am wondering if there is some settings I can change in order for this to work in Release build or any other way to do it

**The Extension:**

```
 public struct Backport<Content> {
     public let content: Content
    
     public init(_ content: Content) {
            self.content = content
     }
 }
        
 extension View {
     var backport: Backport<Self> { Backport(self) }
 }
        
 extension Backport where Content: View {
     @ViewBuilder func badge(_ count: Int) -> some View {
          if #available(iOS 15, *) {
              content.badge(count)
          } else {
              content 
          }
     }
 }
```

The code that is running the extension and giving error:

```
 NavigationView{
     ActivityView()
         .backport.badge(10)   <-- Error
 }
```

It gives the following error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Comment: try changing `Self` to one of the opaque type ways to specify the type such as `some View`

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with backward compatibility, but solved it with this extension:

```
// MARK: - modify
/// A modify extension to handle iOS versions.
public extension View {
    func modify<Content>(@ViewBuilder _ transform: (Self) -> Content) -> Content {
        transform(self)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
TextField(title.rawValue + " username", text: $text.bound)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .modify {
                    if #available(iOS 15, *) {
                        $0
                            .textInputAutocapitalization(.none)
                    } else {
                        $0
                            .autocapitalization(.none)
                    }
                }
```

Comment: The problem is not with the view modifier, but with the #available inside ViewBuilder